Linux arm64 - GPU acceleration?
I've installed Blender via Ubuntu's repos on Ubuntu 24.04.1 on an Ampere Altra Max workstation. The CPU is already quite capable, but I have an Nvidia RTX A4000 workstation GPU (Compute Capability 8.6 according to this chart) in this machine, with full 3D acceleration via CUDA, etc.
The version that's installed is Blender 4.0.2, and everything seems to work great, but when I go into Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices, and select "CUDA", it says:

No compatible GPUs found for Cycles
Requires NVIDIA GPU with compute capability 3.0

For context, here's the output of nvidia-smi on this system:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A4000               Off |   00000004:01:00.0  On |                  Off |
| 41%   32C    P8              7W /  140W |     686MiB /  16376MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4816      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            151MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5019      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          104MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17063      G   ...irefox/4792/usr/lib/firefox/firefox        154MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     23728      G   /usr/bin/nautilus                              28MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     26742    C+G   /usr/bin/blender                              193MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Is it possible I just need a newer version of Blender, or does Blender not yet support GPU acceleration on arm64 Linux? (And if not, where could I look to monitor progress or try to help get that going?)
I also wanted to test my Ampere/arm64 system with the Blender Benchmark, but it looks like the tool is only compiled for x86/AMD64 on Linux, not arm64.

According to GitHub user jackpot51, you have to align CUDA version to Blender version to get Blender to pick up on CUDA properly: https://github.com/geerlingguy/sbc-reviews/issues/53#issuecomment-2557860174

That sounds like a satisfying answer to me. Could  you flesh it out a bit and post it as an actual answer below? Maybe describe the solution with a bit more detail, and shortly mention the steps required to make it work

You do have the Cuda package installed and not just the Nvidia drivers, yes?

@TheLabCat yes, it is all working properly and other applications like llama/Ollama are able to use CUDA acceleration without issue (confirmed by monitoring with nvtop).
